# Change the CSS value from a file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a keyboard.css file and a keyboard.js file, I am trying to change a css rule

```
.ui-keyboard div { font-size: 1.1em; }
```

I want to change the font size. is there a way to do this without using
`$(".ui-keyboard div").css()`?

I want to change the value before the element is rendered, I want to pass the value in the construction of an element

```
$('.onScreenKeyboard').keyboard({
    zoomLevel: 2
});
```

Edit: to clarify this a bit, the goal is to have a way to change the font-size, without having to go and edit the value on the CSS. I want to create an option in the library that does this:

Inside the constructor I check for options and I change the element,

```
//set Zoom Level
if(o.zoomLevel){
    //Change CSS Here.
}
```

Comment: you need the element to be rendered first before you can manipulate it via javascript. so, the answer is NO. you can do this on server side though.

Comment: yeah - if you have control over the HTML of the page, just override the style using a <style>.ui-keyboard div { font-size: yoursize-em; }</style> after calling the css file

Comment: How about overriding the style rule from `keyboard.css` in an another css file that was declared later or add a internal `<style>` rule in the local page after including `keyboard.css`?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299110/how-do-i-make-changes-in-css-file-using-jquery-or-javascript

Comment: _May be_ you can render the element off viewport and then _birng_ it into the viewport when you've done initialization etc

Comment: @DerekHenderson Actually not the same. I don't want to save the value, I just want to use the constructor to overwrite it, but not applied to a specific object.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you're looking for something like [`CSSStyleSheet`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/CSSStyleSheet)'s [`insertRule`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule) and [`deleteRule`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/CSSStyleSheet/deleteRule).

Here is some code I wrote a while ago to let me modify CSS rules

```
function CSS(sheet) {
    if (sheet.constructor.name === 'CSSStyleSheet') this.sheet = sheet;
    else if (sheet.constructor.name === 'HTMLStyleElement') this.sheet = sheet.sheet;
    else throw new TypeError(sheet + ' is not a StyleSheet');
}
CSS.prototype = {
    constructor : CSS,
    add: function (cssText) {
        return this.sheet.insertRule(cssText, this.sheet.cssRules.length);
    },
    del: function (index) {
        return this.sheet.deleteRule(index);
    },
    edit: function (index, cssText) {
        var i;
        if (index < 0) index = 0;
        if (index >= this.sheet.cssRules.length) return this.add( cssText );
        i = this.sheet.insertRule(cssText, index);
        if (i === index) this.sheet.deleteRule(i + 1);
        return i;
    }
};
```

You'd use it by giving the constructor `CSS` your `<style>` node, or it's *StyleSheet* directly, then using `.edit` with the *index* of the rule and the new rule you want. e.g.

```
// get StyleSheet
var mycss = new CSS(document.querySelector('style[src="keyboard.css"]'));
// edit rule 0
mycss.edit(0, '.ui-keyboard div { font-size: 5em; }');
```

Comment: This seems interesting, ill investigate this further.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following css to the element, initially you wont display it until you run through your library change the style properties then display it.

```
.ui-keyboard div {
     font-size: 1.1em;
     display: none;
}
```

You can also change the font size without jQuery by doing something like:

```
[element].style.fontSize = "25px";
```