# Change the state of a property from CSS class that has a attribute selector using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this HTML line:

`<div id="content" class="slide" data-position="left" ></div>`

and this CSS class with this  [attribute] selector:

```
.slide[data-position="left"] {
    display: none;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is after I click a button the css class will change like this using Javascript

```
.slide[data-position="left"] {
    display: block;
}
```

I tried different methods like adding a new class in the HTML line or adding a inline style="display: block;"  using Javascript:

```
$(".slide").attr('data-position', 'left').css({'display':'block'});
```

that generates

```
<div id="content" class="slide" data-position="left" style="display: block;"></div>
```

but the .css() method doesn't help me at all because I want to change/override .slide[data-position="left"]. The inline doesn't change anything in the CSS stylesheet.

I want to know how to change the state of a property for a specific css class that has a certain [attribute] selector.

I tried to google this issue but it seems that nobody has an answer for this.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: i looked this up for you...

[see top-voted answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299110/how-do-i-make-changes-in-css-file-using-jquery-or-javascript

Comment: Yes I know that CSS is not server-side. I need to change the `display` from `none` to `block`. If I do this manually everything works. I'm willing to try using PHP but I wanted to find out if there is any way to do this from javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of altering the CSS rule directly, you can give the element *another* class corresponding to *another* rule:

```
.slide.active { display: block; }
```

or, if the attribute has importance still:

```
.slide.active[data-position="left"] { display: block; }
```

That rule should go after the existing rule to ensure that a "slide" element that also has the "active" class will be visible.

You'd add the class in JavaScript with

```
$("#content").addClass("active");
```

Comment: This works very well and adds a `active` class: `<div id="content" class="slide active" data-position="left">`. Unfortunately I tried this method before posting here and it doesn't change too much. I forgot to mention that I have a large js code and changing the `.slide[data-position="left"` is a must. I know it sounds awkward. The problem is if I manually change the state of `display`to `block` everything works. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @user3095180 if you could describe more about your situation (preferably by extending your question), it would be easier to give workable suggestions. You haven't really explained *why* you are forced to find a way to modify the CSS.

Comment: Ok. I want to add a menu to a slide. the menu works perfectly but when I'm moving it into the `<div class="slide" data-position="left"></div>` it disappears. The `slide` has this `data-position` that masks the slide when it's closed. When I open the slide the `display` must change to `block`. If I manually change this property everything works. That's why I need to know if I can do it in javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by changing your jQuery selector. At the moment you're using jQuerys `attr` method to target the `data-position` attribute and set its value to left. Instead you need to use the same attribute selector you previously used in your CSS declaration: `.slide[data-position=left]`

What you need to do is change this:

```
$(".slide").attr('data-position', 'left').css({'display':'block'});
```

to this:

```
$(".slide[data-position=left]").css({'display':'block'});
```

The complete jQuery would look like this:

```
$("#clickMe").on("click",function(){

    $(".slide[data-position=left]").css({'display':'block'});

});
```

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kza7mLf4/)

Comment: This is true but I've mentioned that the .css() method doesn't help me because it generates a inline `style="display: block;"`.  Thank you for the tip!